# SDL2 как загрузить картинку (на иконку окна и на курсор)?

Tags: c++, sdl2

Нужно загрузить картинку в SDL_Surface для установки её на иконку окна и на кастомный курсор. Нашел вот этот способ превращения массива пикселей в SDL_Surface: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetWindowIcon
Но тогда появляется вопрос, а как прочитать картинку в массив пикселей? Попробовал разные сайты, конвертирующие картинку в массив пикселей. Такой код:

```
uint8_t pixels[] = {
    0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff, // и т.д, огромное кол-во хексов цифр...
};

SDL_Surface *cursor;
cursor = SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom(pixels, 16, 16, 16, 16*2, 0x0f00, 0x00f0, 0x000f, 0xf000);
SDL_Cursor * c = SDL_CreateColorCursor(cursor, 0,0);
SDL_SetCursor(c);
```

Так вот, картинка отображается вообще не корректно. Её видно только при разрешении 16x16, но при этом цвета глючат, а при бОльшем разрешении картинки так и вовсе ничего. Функция, помимо пикселей и разрешения, принимает ещё какие-то r, g и b -маски, но для чего они нужны, я так и не понял, а также depth и pitch (которые лучше не менять, как я выяснил). Ещё, в примере на сайте цифры явно не такие. Там хексы каких-то пятизначных цифр.

Так как же правильно загружать картинку? Объясните, пожалуйста, новичку в SDL2 (SDL_LoadBMP не предлагать, нужна альфа).

Comment: Это конечно не ответ, но последние версии SDL автоматически устанавливают иконку экзешника как иконку окна (как минимум на windows). Так что не обязательно делать это вручную.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, да, это я уже обнаружил. Но вопрос загрузки изображений это всё равно не решает. Нужен курсор, да и вообще не плохо было бы разобраться...

Comment: Имхо, IMG_Load - самый простой вариант. Как именно он не работает?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, всё, уже починил, нужно было просто докинуть всю ту кучу dll для форматов файлов из архива. Пойду разбираться с SDL2 дальше, в любом случае, спасибо за ответы...
Если найду более хороший способ, напишу здесь же ответ.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, проблема решена.
Нашел на [оф сайте объяснение](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceWithFormatFrom), как с stbimage прочитать картинку в SDL-овский формат.

Ещё нашел на просторах гитхаба [библиотеку](https://github.com/DanielGibson/Snippets/blob/master/SDL_stbimage.h) как stb_image, только совмещенную с SDL2, но в ней почему-то работают не все форматы изображения.

Первый способ наиболее рабочий.

Comment: А чем SDL2_image не понравился? Он же у вас вроде заработал?